# returning sys_refcursor from oracle in SAP BODS

Tags: oracle, plsql, sap-data-services, sap-business-technology-platform

I want to write a sript in BODS which will call an Oracle SP, which upon passing 2 parameters will return a sys_refcursor containing 3-4 columns. How to write such a script so that that returned value can be stored in a variable and displayed.

Comment: BODS is for data transformation. How do you want to display it?

Comment: I want to call an Stored procedure in SQL script from Oracle. The script deletes data from table. The created job will then be scheduled. But I don't know what script to write